# Not retrieving data from Table per concrete type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I have implemented Table Per Concrete Type in entity framework as follows

I have Vehicle and OldVehicle tables. Vehicle is base entity and OldVehicle is derived entity.

I have removed all the overlapping properties from the derived entity i.e., OldVehicle.

Now I try to retrieve the data from OldVehicle as follows :

```
CarRentalModelEntities context = new CarRentalModelEntities();
var oldVeh = context.Vehicles.OfType<OldVehicle>();
foreach (var oh in oldVeh)
{
    --Some Code Here--                   
}
```

I have 9 records in my OldVehicle table.

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: Not sure. I am not getting any error message.

Comment: Show the mappings please.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add some of the properties of OldVehicles in the XMl. Now I get result.

Thank you Gert Arnold for asking about Mappings.